# Why ids in urls don't work but slugs do?

Tags: urls, slug, id

I'm lost, I don't understand why this works

```
http://website.com/?tag=my-cat-slug
```

and not this

```
http://website.com/?tag=15
```

It's really annoying because `wp_dropdown_categories()` only provides ids as values.

I tried to change permalinks to default settings instead of rewriting:

```
http://website.com/?p=123
```

But it changed nothing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the `tag` query variable expects the value to the terms slug. It'll be looking for the term with slug '15' (which presumably doesn't exist).

And, yes its quite frustrating that `wp_dropdown_categories()` uses the ID as the value, rather than the slug. This is because it was originally used only for categories (for which IDs rather than slugs are generally used) as opposed to general taxonomies.

However, there is [this ticket on it](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13258). I have created [this gist](https://gist.github.com/2902509), which can allow you to make `wp_dropdown_categories()` use slugs rather than IDs for the value.

For reference (the following class should go in a plug-in):

```
/* 
 * A walker class to use that extends wp_dropdown_categories and allows it to use the term's slug as a value rather than ID.
 *
 * See http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13258
 *
 * Usage, as normal:
 * wp_dropdown_categories($args);
 *
 * But specify the custom walker class, and (optionally) a 'id' or 'slug' for the 'value' parameter:
 * $args=array('walker'=> new SH_Walker_TaxonomyDropdown(), 'value'=>'slug', .... );
 * wp_dropdown_categories($args);
 * 
 * If the 'value' parameter is not set it will use term ID for categories, and the term's slug for other taxonomies in the value attribute of the term's <option>.
*/

class SH_Walker_TaxonomyDropdown extends Walker_CategoryDropdown{

    function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ){
        $pad = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $depth * 3);
        $cat_name = apply_filters('list_cats', $category->name, $category);

        if( !isset($args['value']) ){
            $args['value'] = ( $category->taxonomy != 'category' ? 'slug' : 'id' );
        }

        $value = ($args['value']=='slug' ? $category->slug : $category->term_id );

        $output .= "\t<option class=\"level-$depth\" value=\"".$value."\"";
        if ( $value === (string) $args['selected'] ){   
            $output .= ' selected="selected"';
        }
        $output .= '>';
        $output .= $pad.$cat_name;
        if ( $args['show_count'] )
            $output .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;('. $category->count .')';

        $output .= "</option>\n";
        }

}
```

### Usage

```
$args=array(
    'walker'=> new SH_Walker_TaxonomyDropdown(), 
    'value'=>'slug', 
     .... 
);
wp_dropdown_categories($args);
```

The 'value' parameter optional. The default value will be 'id' for categories, and 'slug' for other taxonomies.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I had seen your solution on different websites. I ended up using it but all the options  were `selected="selected"` on my homepage so I changed `if ( $value == $args['selected'] )` into `if ( !empty($args['selected']) AND $value == $args['selected'] )`

I also had to replace `if ( $args['show_count'] )` by `if ( isset($args['show_count']) AND $args['show_count'] )` in order to get rid of all the **notice errors** and **warning errors** in PHP.

Comment: Actually the only thing causing an error should be the `'show_last_update'`, which I shall remove. The rest should all be set because of they are sent through `wp_parse_args` (https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4.1/wp-includes/category-template.php#L321)

Comment: I noticed it only because I submit with Javascript, otherwise I would not have guessed all the `selected="selected"`. Concerning the **notice errors* I notice them only because on my dev webserver I like to put WP_DEBUG=ON

Comment: I have too :), but I don't get any errors regarding `show_count` or `selected`. They should exist in the `$args` because of the line linked to above. Concerning `selected="selected"` appearing everywhere... oops. Sloppy php coding. `'string' == 0` always returns true. I'll edit the answer...

Comment: +1 And yes, another very annoying thing one encounters (and is left with a lot of question marks if he doesn't know why).

Comment: I get this error `[14-Mar-2014 22:14:05 UTC] PHP Strict Standards:  Declaration of SH_Walker_TaxonomyDropdown::start_el() should be compatible with Walker_CategoryDropdown::start_el(&$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = Array, $id = 0)` any suggestions?

Comment: @HarishChouhan the stric error is because the over-riding method doesn't declare the same number of variables as the method its over-riding method. (Fixed now).